# Identification of Consecutive day Availability with Islands

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem where I need to define a schedule based on available spaces, and skills, over consecutive days.

The dataset is provided in the following format:

[Location] | [Class ID] | [Date] | [Room] | [Available]

The results are expected to be formatted similar to an tiered cake, where the bottom layer has the most number of available spots across the longest date range.  the next layer would contain the remaining rooms that span the most consecutive days, and so forth.

Does anyone have any ideas on how you could solve this?

I have created a quick qry to obtain the groups of consecutive days:

```
SELECT [LOCATION], ROOM_ID, CLASS_ID, [DATE]
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_ID ORDER BY [DATE]), [DATE]) AS DT_GRP
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_ID ORDER BY [DATE]) ROWID
FROM dbo.LECTURE_SPACE
```

And getting the Min/Max of Date grouped on DT_GRP identifies the correct start/end days of the 'layers'.
I am hung up on how beset to identify the next layer, should the available spaces to added to the above, etc.

Does anyone have any thoughts? and Thank you in advance for your help.

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #LECTURE_SPACE
(
[LOCATION] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CLASS_ID NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ROOM_ID NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[DATE] DATE NOT NULL,
AVAIL DECIMAL(19,0) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/01/2020'),4);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/02/2020'),4);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/03/2020'),1);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/04/2020'),5);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/05/2020'),6);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/07/2020'),6);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/08/2020'),1);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/10/2020'),6);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/11/2020'),7);
INSERT INTO #LECTURE_SPACE  VALUES('BROOKS', '1020', 'Room 109', ('01/12/2020'),6);

SELECT [LOCATION], ROOM_ID, CLASS_ID, [DATE]
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_ID ORDER BY [DATE]), [DATE]) AS DT_GRP
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_ID ORDER BY [DATE]) ROWID
FROM #LECTURE_SPACE
```

With Results Expected as:
[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sTnC.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: You are right, that would be helpful.  Adding to the main body of the question.